# Using git rev-parse with --parseopt to access named arguments in a shell script

Tags: linux, git, shell, scripting, git-bash

When using the `--parseopt` option with `git rev-parse`, it outputs a string that can be passed to `eval`, e.g.

```
set -- --foo --bar=arg 'test' --
```

After running this command via `eval`, it sets $1 to "--foo", $2 to "--bar=arg", and $3 to "test". My question is, does the `set` command do any magic besides setting positional arguments that would allow my script to access options by name? Or do I have to manually loop through the arguments and check the names myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no magic, but you can change what is `eval`ed to something else, so you can access by name.  For example:

```
$ eval `git rev-parse --foo --bar=arg | sed -r 's/--//g; /^[^=]+$/s/$/=/'
$ echo $bar
arg
$ [[ ${foo+t} ]] && echo y
y
$ if [[ ${baz+t} ]]; then echo y; else echo n; fi
n
```

The sed removes the leading `--` and for lines without an `=`, adds one to the end.  When the shell evals a line like `foo=` it sets a variable named `foo` to an empty string.  You can test that `foo` is set with `[[ ${foo+t} ]]` (`t` is arbitrary, I choose `t` as a mnemonic for true). You could also set the variable to some sentinel value in the sed, and then use a simple `[[ $foo ]]` test.

Depending on the variety of arguments you need to support, you may need to tweak the sed.   Using `set -xv` will show you everything that's happening so you can make changes:

```
$ set -xv
$ eval `git rev-parse --foo --bar=arg | sed -r 's/--//g; /^[^=]+$/s/$/=/'`
eval `git rev-parse --foo --bar=arg | sed -r 's/--//g; /^[^=]+$/s/$/=/'`
git rev-parse --foo --bar=arg | sed -r 's/--//g; /^[^=]+$/s/$/=/'
++ sed -r 's/--//g; /^[^=]+$/s/$/=/'
++ git rev-parse --foo --bar=arg
+ eval foo= bar=arg
foo= bar=arg
++ foo=
++ bar=arg
```

Comment: Thanks; guess I'll have to get familiar with `sed`. Not really seeing the point of `--parseopt` though.

Comment: With `--parseopt` you can specify which flags are acceptable with the `opt-spec`.  Any unknown flags cause an error.

Comment: Regarding `sed`, that just happens to be the tool I used.  There are other options, like `awk`.   Still, the use of regular expressions is pretty common to text processing on Linux/Unix/OS X.